# UserProfile in the admin dashboard - doesn't appear

Tags: python, django, django-1.7

I want the user to be able to login and logout only, but not edit their profile themselves, only the admin can register and edit the user and their profile.

```
# my_app/models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)


# my_app/admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from my_app.models import UserProfile

admin.site.register(UserProfile)
```

After applying the migrations there's still no "field1" and "field2" in the admin dashboard. How come?

[image]
[image]

```
#settings.py
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

SECRET_KEY = '!&d@p=()6crkiyu=z1$_vsr%2or#v3396@f7n9tvwykd+o9^ol'

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1']

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'grappelli_extensions',
    'grappelli',
    'my_app',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'my_project.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'my_project.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'some_db_dev',                      
        'USER': 'user1',
        'PASSWORD': '.....$',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1'
    }
}

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

LOGIN_URL = '/login'
```

Comment: Have you restarted the development server, and logged out and logged in again to the admin site?

Comment: Please post your `settings.py`.

Comment: Are you sure you're viewing the UserProfile page in the admin dashboard? It looks like you're trying to view the User page.

Comment: @RodXavier, no, I'm not viewing it because there's no link to it. Shouldn't the fields be on /users/:id page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have just created a user model called `UserProfile`, but have not modified the admin so that it is shown along with the normal (built-in) `User` model.

Please see the [documentation on extending the `User` model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) for more details - make sure you are viewing the page for the version of django you are using.

To just adjust the profile as a normal model, you need to view its own change form, which should be available from the main admin landing page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `inlines` for User model in admin.py. For example:

```py
class UserProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
   model = UserProfile

class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   inlines = [
      UserProfileInline,
   ]

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

and now you can see fields of `UserProfile` at User admin form.